# Jquery set counter, but reset when function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout, setinterval

Does anyone know what function would be best to use for the following scenario?

When a song starts playing, I want to start a 'stopwatch' that counts up in seconds.

At any point, i'd like to be able to call this variable, such as a button that you click that'll do `alert(time)` and reveal the count on the timer.

But, when i run a function `reset-timer();` I'd like this all to reset and start counting again.

I was thinking settimeout or setinterval but not sure which is correct.

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you need, code to count and display the time, or code to reset the counter? Your post isn't clear.

Comment: either setTimeout or setInterval be can be correct. Heck if you do not need something updating, you do not even need an interval. Give some pseudo code on what you want to happen.

Comment: Keep track of the start-time.
  Use setInterval to display the difference. Reset the start-time if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic concept to get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/V29qK/1/

```
var startTime = new Date();

function SetTime(){
    var curTime = new Date();

    var seconds = Math.round((curTime - startTime) / 1000) + " second(s)";
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
}


var interval = setInterval(SetTime, 1000);

function ResetTime(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "0 second(s)";
    startTime = new Date();
}
​
```

The logic is: Set a global variable to a `new Date()` to signify the Start Time. On an interval (or timeout), get the current `new Date()` and subtract the Start Time from it. This will give you the difference in milliseconds. You can then update whatever UI element you want with this data.

To "Reset" the timer, you simply set the Start Time to the current time with `new Date()`

Comment: if you want to have minutes too jquery has some pretty easy ways to keep track of minutes too

Comment: Thanks Shmiddty! This is awesome and exactly what I wanted! So it's setInterval..I'll plug this code in and get you your checkmark in a few minutes! @TMP do you have a link so I could read about it ?

Comment: the link is http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp, but shmiddty's example is pretty stellar, all you'd have to do for that is divide by 60 to get the minutes and the remainder can stay seconds.  and oops that's just the plain js version, i don't remember if that's what i used or if there's a jquery one too